# Show that the set $E$ consists of Isolated point is countable

Tags: real-analysis

Show that is a set $E$ consists of isolated points, then it is countable.

Proof:

Let $x \in E$ be an isolated point. By definition, the exist an interval $(x-r,x+r) \cap E={x}$ where $r>0$. So now in order to show that the set of E is countable i need to find a a bijection between the set of $E$ and $N$. Let $ \psi : E \mapsto N$ be a function define as....

this is where i am struggling i do not know how to find such function that will help me with the bijection. any idea thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Directly creating such a function is unnecessarily complicated. Instead, define $U_n = \left\{x \in [-n, n]\mid \left(x - \frac{1}{n}, x + \frac{1}{n}\right) \cap E = \{x\}\right\}$ and show that $E = \bigcup \limits_{n = 1}^\infty U_n$ is a countable collection of finite sets.

Comment: I am trying to show that the E is a countable collection of finite sets i am still having a hard time showing that. I guess i do not know what am i looking for to answer the question. In order words what do i need in order to show that E is countable. Usually by definition i look to find a bijection function, but it is not the case here, so no how do i think about it

Comment: Most often it's too complicated to create explicit bijections between two sets, so you rely on certain theorems. One such theorem is that the countable union of finite [or even countable] sets is again countable. It is much easier to prove your statement by using this theorem. You just need to show that $E$ actually is the union of all $U_n$ and that all $U_n$ are finite.

Comment: Apologies for commenting on an old post/solution, but I (think I) built a collection of disjoint, open intervals similar to what the solution below suggests where it didn't seem complicated (if I'm correct) -- except I did it rigorously, and I did not use that method. Namely, I showed for any $x,y\in E$ where $x\neq y$ then there is a $\delta>0$ such that $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\cap(y-\delta,y+\delta)=\varnothing$ and concluded there exists a disjoint, open cover for $E$. Does that work, are more details needed, etc.? Trying to avoid posting a solution for an old post or a dup question I suppose.

Comment: @Procore Then your set must be at most countable. I suggest you open a new question to show your exact prerequisites and reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

Create a set of disjoint open intervals, each containing one isolated point.  Using half the supremum of 'r' as the radius of your interval will work, as none of these intervals will intersect.  This makes a bijection between a set of open intervals and E.

Next, note that a disjoint set of nonempty open intervals is countable, since each one contains a unique rational number - thus, there is a one-one function between your disjoint set and Q.